# My first JavaScript calendar project

Tags: javascript, datetime, dom

I have just finished writing my first Javascript project, a calendar, and I want to find out if my code is readable for other developers. In this version I used JS only, I didn't use any libraries. Also, I preferred to use DOM instead of the 'string methods' for html elements.

During my JS course, the tutor always said  it is essential that the code is well explained, well constructed and readable to others. Can you please take a look at it and tell me, would you consider this a well written code, readability-wise?

---

```
window.onload = function () {
    initMonths();
    createYears();
    initButtons();
    var cal = new Calendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    listenMonths();
    listenYears();
    cal.generateHTML();
    cal.fillTheRows();
    showMonthAndYear();
}


//globals

let currentDate = new Date();
let currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
let WEEK_DAYS = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
let MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
let MONTHS_DURATIONS = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
let START_YEAR = 1990;
let END_YEAR = 2020;

let thead = document.getElementsByTagName('thead');

// Header

function initMonths() {
    let select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    MONTHS.forEach(function(current, index, arr) {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', index);
        option.setAttribute('id', 'month' + index);
        option.innerHTML = current;
        select.appendChild(option);

        if (index === currentMonth) {
            option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
}

// Months' event listener
function listenMonths() {
    let select = document.getElementById('months');
    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        currentMonth = +this.value;
        showCal();
    });
}

function createYears() {
    let select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1];

    for (var i = START_YEAR; i <= END_YEAR; i++) {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', i);
        option.setAttribute('id', 'year' + i);
        option.innerHTML = i;

        if (i === currentYear) {
            option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }

        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}

//Years' event listener
function listenYears() {
    let select = document.getElementById('years');
    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        currentYear = this.value;
        showCal();
    });
}

function initButtons() {
    let prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');

    prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let opt = document.getElementById('month' + currentMonth);

        if (currentMonth != 0) {
            currentMonth -= 1;
        }
        showCal();
    });

    let nextButton = document.getElementById('next');

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let opt = document.getElementById('month' + currentMonth);

        if (currentMonth != 11) {
            currentMonth += 1;
        }
        showCal();
    });
}

function showMonthAndYear() {
    let heading = document.getElementById('calTitle');
    heading.innerHTML = `${MONTHS[currentMonth]} ${currentYear}`;
}




// body

function showCal() {
    var cal = new Calendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    cal.clearRows();
    cal.fillTheRows();
    showMonthAndYear();
}

function Calendar(month, year) {
    this.month = (isNaN(month) || month == null) ? currentDate.getMonth() : month;
    this.year = (isNaN(year) || year == null) ? currentDate.getFullYear() : year;

    let firstDay = new Date(year, month, 0);
    let startingDay = firstDay.getDay();
    let monthLength = MONTHS_DURATIONS[month];



    this.generateHTML = function() {
        function getWeekdayNames() {
            let createRow = document.createElement('tr');
            createRow.setAttribute('id', 'weekdayNames');
            let thead = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
            thead.appendChild(createRow);
            let weekdayRow = document.getElementById('weekdayNames');
            for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
                let createCell = document.createElement('td');
                createCell.innerHTML = WEEK_DAYS[i];
                weekdayRow.appendChild(createCell);
            }
        }

        getWeekdayNames();

        function generateRows() {

            let tbody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
            //rows or weeks
            let condition = (startingDay >= 4) ? 6 : 5;
            for (let i = 0; i < condition; i++) {
                let createRow = document.createElement('tr');
                createRow.setAttribute('id', 'row' + i);
                tbody.appendChild(createRow);
                //columns or weekdays
                for (let j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { 
                    let createCell = document.createElement('td');
                    createCell.setAttribute('id', 'cell' + i + j);
                    let currentRow = document.getElementById('row' + i);                        
                    currentRow.appendChild(createCell);
                }
            }
        }
        generateRows();
    }

    this.fillTheRows = function() {
        let day = 1;

        //leap year fix
        if (this.month == 1) {
            if (this.year % 4 === 0 && this.year % 100 != 0 || this.year % 400 === 0) {
                monthLength = 29;
            }
        }

        //rows
        let condition = (startingDay >= 4) ? 6 : 5;
        for (let i = 0; i < condition; i++) {

            if (i === 5 && !document.getElementById('row' + i)) {
                let sundayOfThe5thWeek = document.getElementById('cell' + 4 + 6);
                if (sundayOfThe5thWeek.innerHTML < monthLength) {
                    let createRow = document.createElement('tr');
                    createRow.setAttribute('id', 'row' + 5);
                    for (let k = 0; k <= 6; k++) {
                        createCell = document.createElement('td');
                        createCell.setAttribute('id', 'cell' + 5 + k);
                        createRow.appendChild(createCell);
                    }
                    let tbody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
                    tbody.appendChild(createRow);
                }
            }
            //columns or weekdays
            let j = i === 0 ? startingDay : 0;
            for (j; j <= 6; j++) {
                if (day <= monthLength) {
                    let currentRow = document.getElementById('row' + i);
                    if (!currentRow) {
                        fixMissingRow(i);
                    }
                    let currentCell = document.getElementById('cell' + i + j);
                    currentCell.innerHTML = day;
                    if (day === monthLength && currentRow.nextSibling) {
                        currentRow.nextSibling.remove();
                        return;                     
                    }
                    day++;
                }

                if (day > monthLength) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            function fixMissingRow(index) {
                let addRow = document.createElement('tr');
                addRow.setAttribute('id', 'row' + index);
                for (let j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { 
                    let createCell = document.createElement('td');
                    createCell.setAttribute('id', 'cell' + index + j);
                    addRow.appendChild(createCell);
                }
                let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
                tableBody.appendChild(addRow);

            }
        }
    }

    this.clearRows = function() {
        let monthLength = MONTHS_DURATIONS[month];

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            //columns or weekdays
            for (let j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
                let currentRow = document.getElementById('row' + i);
                let currentCell = document.getElementById('cell' + i + j);
                if(!currentCell) {
                    break;
                }
                currentCell.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.  It would be helpful to add a link to the working calendar using jsfiddle or SO's own snippet runner.

Comment: your tutor tells you it's essential to have well explained code yet the longest comment you have is three words long. maybe take your tutor's advice before asking for others' advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DOM Querying is a heavy task for browser.

- Execute document.query only once. It is a very heavy task for browser. Best approach would be to query them at the top of the file and assign it to a variable.
- clearRows method -

  1. `monthLength` variable not used.
  2. querying is being done from document. Instead query from nearest element.

> Functions should not be inside a loop. Functions are objects. Each time a function is declared, it creates a new object. A new object will take more memory.

- move `fixMissingRow` out of the loop. So it needs to be kept in a place which gets executed only once.

> Constructor function definition should be minimal
>   Keep following functions as part of the function prototype. In our case it should be part of `Calendar.prototype`

- `generateHTML`
- `getWeekdayNames`
- `generateRows`
- `fillTheRows`
- `fixMissingRow`
- `clearRows`